# Azure Devops dump files - how to get them

Tags: azure-devops

When running tests I can see the following logged:

d:\work_temp\TestResults\testhost_1188_2987d14292c64d298300326618cc0d9d.dmp

Sometimes I can see them attached to an individual test but sometimes ( maybe if dump is in setup / shutdown ) I can't find the dump file.

Is there some job / step I need to configured to attach the dump files as an artifact or something?

We are using NUnit. vstest@2.
I think the dump file creation is created because of the setting:

diagnosticsEnabled: True

The YAML is:

```
  - ${{each testItem in parameters.testsToRun}}:

- task: VSTest@2
  timeoutInMinutes: ${{parameters.testtimeout}}
  displayName: 'Run ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}
    searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\bin\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)'
    runSettingsFile: RunSettings.runsettings
    runTestsInIsolation: false
    testRunTitle: ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    diagnosticsEnabled: True
    testFiltercriteria : ${{testItem.testFiltercriteria}}
  continueOnError: ${{parameters.continueonError}}
```

Comment: What's generating this file? What's placing it in that location? What testing framework are you using? Please provide as many specific details as possible about the situation.

Comment: @DanielMann - added some details.

Comment: Is `d:\work_temp` your pipeline agent's configured working directory? As in, the contents of `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` maps to `D:\work_temp`?

Comment: It's pretty easy to add a step to upload those files as an artifact, even if the `VSTest` task fails to do so. Is this something your looking for or there is more to your question? I had a look at the `VSTest` task [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/VsTestV2) and it's a bit messier that other tasks IMO, so it's not clear why those orphan dumps happen.

Comment: I think adding a step to upload those file would probably be all I need.